# Manipulating csv data in powershell 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am going nutty trying to understand my issue. Normally in Powershell I do an import-csv and I get a nice output that looks something like:

```
col1 : Mary.jane.doe
Col2 : John
```

Which I can then easily move around and do whatever I want really. But I have file that gives me:

```
col1                  col2
----                  ----
Mary.jane.doe         John
```

I need to be able to do a split on the first column and put it into a variable  so I just get "Mary", then put that into its own column so my output looks like:

```
col1                  col2                  col3
----                  ----                  ----- 
Mary                  Mary.jane.doe         John
```

Thanks in advance for answers, also what would I need to really study in Powershell to understand how this is working, as this is the first time I have pulled my hair out with manipulating csv,txt files etc...
In Powershell? Most of the machines I work on have Powershell2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start with, you need to update your OS since PowerShell 2.0 is only default on versions of Windows that are out of support now I'm pretty sure. That aside, this can be done fairly simply a few ways. Since you are going to be changing the column headers for each column (per your example), I would pipe the CSV data through a `ForEach-Object` loop, and create a new object based off each existing object, and output that.

```
$MyCSV = Import-Csv C:\Path\To\File.csv
$NewCSV = $MyCSV | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        'Col1' = $_.Col1.Split('.')[0]
        'Col2' = $_.Col1
        'Col3' = $_.Col2
        }
} | Select-Object col1, col2, col3
```

<sup>Editor's note: PSv2 didn't support defining a custom object's properties *in order*, which is why the `Select-Object` call is needed to ensure the desired property enumeration order. In PSv3+ you can create custom objects as `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`, which does respect the property-definition order.</sup>

This iterates the CSV, and for each record makes a new record with your desired properties. Like I said, there's a few ways to accomplish this, but I think this would be the simplest considering your needs.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TheMadTechnician; I appreciate the nice feedback, and also appreciate the quality of your answers here.